# Rails 3.2.13 - Assets are not displayed in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, assets, production

I've spent the whole day trying to figure out this issue, but without any positive results.
When I load my website, there are no CSS, images or working javascript.

The app is running on Rails `3.2.13` and Capistrano 2.

Here's my setup:

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
Appname::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  #config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', 'application.css', 'styles.css.scss', '*.css.erb']
  config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.svg *.woff *.ttf *.ico)

  config.assets.digest = true
  config.cache_store = :memory_store

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end

module Apname
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    config.assets.enabled = true

    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
    config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/

    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  end
end
```

I ran locally `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` -> the files were generated to the `public/assets` directory.

But still -- there are no assets on production.

I have already no idea what to change in the config files, still the same result on the production server.

Every help will be warmly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I just noticed in the console that images are loaded correctly (I can load `http://website.com/assets/social_icons/facebook_ico.png`), but not CSS+JS (`http://IP/assets/application-3b6ba7703e465259e4e7ebee17c5ea1e.js` 404 NOT FOUND - the same for .css)

Comment: I see the module is called "Apname" but the configuration is looking for "Appname" - just a typo in your example, or is this copied from the actual code? If you call it one thing, and then try to access a different thing... problems!

Comment: `Appname` is just a placeholder there, in the code is the real name of the app.

Comment: I assume you're using 'git' to push to production? Have you allowed git to record the assets, in the branch you're pushing live? They're actually in the repo and not ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to restart the webserver after compiling the assets?

Are the rights set correctly (`chmod 755 . -R`)?

Also, check that your webserver configuration points to *app_root/public* and not just *app_root*

EDIT1:

Check if you can load the url directly. In addition verify that the rendered page display correctly-cached urls.

If one of the two fails try forcing compilation for production environment

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

EDIT2:
If nothing works try rolling back to default assets config for production:

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

instead of:

```
  #config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  config.assets.compress = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', 'application.css', 'styles.css.scss', '*.css.erb']
  config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.svg *.woff *.ttf *.ico)

  config.assets.digest = true
```

EDIT 3:

> EDIT:
>
> I just noticed in the console that images are loaded correctly (I can
>   load http://website.com/assets/social_icons/facebook_ico.png), but not
>   CSS+JS
>   (http://****/assets/application-3b6ba7703e465259e4e7ebee17c5ea1e.js 404
>   NOT FOUND - the same for .css)

That also means you aren't actually compiling assets. If you were, you'd need to load facebook_ico.png with the hash attached to the name

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message. Yes, the server is restarted after every deployment + it's pointed on the **public** dir + the permissions are correct too.